# How do you configure MongoMapper 0.11 with MONGOHQ_URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, heroku, mongomapper, mongohq

I want to run MongoMapper on Heroku. This necessitates MongoHQ. All the documentation, like http://mongomapper.com/documentation/getting-started/rails.html, tells you to create an initializer to connect to Mongo with the MONGOHQ_URL environment variable. However, recent versions on MongoMapper don't require an initializer, it just connects automatically now based on the content of config/mongo.yml.

Here inlies the problem: mongo.yml doesn't seem to allow me to connect with a URL, only with host, port, etc. I tried the following and it didn't work for me:

```
production:
  url: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
```

Any other ideas on how to get this working?

(the error I get when deploying to heroku is that the app is trying to connect to localhost:27017 and failing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait I figured it out...

```
production:
  uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
```

(uri, not url)